# Why is an array field saved with '[]' in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Currently I am saving data to a mongo db using the following route in my Node JS app.

```
var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get('jobs');
req.body.employer = req.user.username;          //update the employer id
req.body.companyname = req.user.companyname;    //update the company name

collection.insert(req.body, function(err, result){
    res.send(
        (err === null) ? { msg: '' } : { msg: err }
    );
});
```

The req.body is built like this:

```
var newJob = {
        'employer': '-',
        'companyname': '-',
        'title': $('#addJob input#jobTitle').val(),
        'payrate': $('#addJob input#payRate').val(),
        'posteddate': datetime,
        'durationstart': $('#addJob input#startDate').val(),
        'durationend': $('#addJob input#endDate').val(),
        'workinghrs': $('#addJob input#workingHours').val(),
        'location': $('#addJob input#location').val(),
        'experience': experience[experience.selectedIndex].value,
        'equipment': equipment,
        'status': $('#addJob input#status').is(":checked"),
        'description': $('#addJob textarea#description').val()
    }

    //alert(newJob.toString());

    // Use AJAX to post the object to our addJob service
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: newJob,
        url: '/jobs/addJob',
        dataType: 'JSON'
    }).done(function( response ) {
           //blah blah
    }
```

Now if you notice the 'equipment' that is actually an array. This works fine, however, when I look at the values in my database, it looks like the following:

```
"equipment[]": [
    "Hardhat",
    "Steel Toe Boots",
    "fghjfg"
],
```

My question is, why is the equipment field being saved with the name 'equipment[]'? In my code which sets up the body or my document I am setting it as 'equipment'. This is causing an issue when I try to get the value of that array because now I have to refer to it as 'equipment[]'.

Any ideas why this is happening and how I can prevent it from being saved as 'equipment[]'?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which Mongo driver do you use here? Native one I suppose?

Comment: Yes, native Mongo driver.

Comment: I would suggest using body-parser to transform arrays and object properly to your req.body. do you use body-parser in your app ?

Comment: @DimaGrossman nope, not even sure what that is. I will have to look into it and try it out.